# How to force employees to complete security awareness quiz?

Tags: windows, awareness

The idea is that when a user logs in PC (Windows 10) he should be forced to complete a quiz before he could start work.

These are company owned laptops.

The quiz will be few questions short, shown periodically with different questions.

Also want to show users important information. Management accepted. We can work/teach employees individually who failed the quiz.

One option would be some kind of app on startup in full-screen mode.

Second option would be where the user can't access the internet without completing this quiz (as seen on public WiFi AP with guest login).

Or are there better options?

Comment: You ask for better options, but what's wrong with the ones you have? What further benefits are you looking for?

Comment: @schroeder I think its more in the vein of "will this fail horribly for reasons I haven't thought about?" c.f. every password rule ever.

Comment: ...speaking of, Bitenieks, if I we're responding to an all hands critical business emergency and had to divert to answer a dinky security quiz, I'd be calling for your head on a plate...

Comment: @JaredSmith the question asked is "how" not "should". The original version even asked for tools to implement it. Management has approved the scheme. As an expert in the field, I can fill a page with why this shouldn't happen, but it seems to be an open-ended question (which I am shortly to close).

Comment: @JaredSmith that's why I asked about failure of the quiz - just answer A to everything to click your way through

Comment: @schroeder fair enough, no objections.

Comment: I would suggest to make the quiz on paper distribute it through team leaders to everyone.